# Apply mask a string in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all in my project i want a currency in three formats,.

```
1) ...999,999,999
2) ...999,999,999.00
3) ...999,999,99
```

The format is specified in mysql data table field. My project is in ASP.NET so I can't use MaskedTextBox . Code I tried:

```
String.Format("{999,999,999}",rate);
```

and

```
rate.ToString("999,999,999).
```

How to get the mask string?

Comment: I've removed random "don't get it" from your post... But it is still not clear what you want to achive. Are you looking for correct format strting to output values of some type? Or trying to do some sort of validation? Or trying to hide (mask?) something?

Comment: i want output values. my input is 1000000 then i need 1,000,000 like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For forcing an input to be in your specified format, use the AJAX Control Toolkit `MaskedEdit` control.

For outputting a number as a string in a specific format, look at the following pages:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Either create a string format and put it directly in the `ToString` function, or create a special `NumberFormatInfo`, with the following options:

- **CurrencyPositivePattern**: Defines the placement of the currency symbol for positive values.
- **CurrencyNegativePattern**: Defines the placement of the currency symbol for negative values, and specifies whether the negative sign is represented by parentheses or the NegativeSign property.
- **NegativeSign**: Defines the negative sign used if CurrencyNegativePattern indicates that parentheses are not used.
- **CurrencySymbol**: Defines the currency symbol.
- **CurrencyDecimalDigits**: Defines the default number of decimal digits in a currency value. This value can be overridden by using the precision specifier.
- **CurrencyDecimalSeparator**: Defines the string that separates integral and decimal digits.
- **CurrencyGroupSeparator**: Defines the string that separates groups of integral numbers.
- **CurrencyGroupSizes**: Defines the number of integer digits that appear in a group.

Comment: Not sure if there is a format which leaves out the last digit, it makes no sense. Easiest solution could be to `ToString("###,###,###")` and then trim the last character.

Answer (score 2):

You should have to download the [AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) and use `MaskedEdit` control.

EDIT:

Use [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Comment: actually i need to display the string in that three formats. no need to getting input. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

> rate.ToString("###,###,###").

Comment: what is the meaning of the # symbol?. so i want to use # for 9?